# eclipse, iterator, template map, not accessing first ... C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, templates, dictionary, iterator

I am trying to create a general function for printing all values in a map (any type of map)
for example I have:

```
map<string, Movie*> movieMap;
map<int, Professional*> proMap;
```

both Movie and Professional have << defined for them.
soooo the iteration function should look like this (according to what I understand):

```
template<typename TYPE, typename TYPE2>
void System::printAll(map<TYPE, TYPE2*> m) {
    for(typename map<TYPE, TYPE2*>::const_iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++) {
        cout << *m[it->first]; //issue is here
    }
}
```

The problem is:
eclipse is not giving me the option "first" when I write "it->" and then ctl-space...
What is the problem here and what would be the easiest way to achieve my goal of making a generic function of printing all values of a map?

Thanks all!

Comment: Eclipse is just a tool you use to develop a program in many different languages. Rather than telling us you are using Eclipse you should be telling us what programming language this is!

Comment: oh! sorry...added (c++)